# ifelse calc displays correctly in console but not in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

When I run the following code it displays correctly in the console, but the data frame is incorrect and every row displays "IDK"

```
#sample data
x <- data.frame("ID" = 1:5, "action" = c("Assists","Goals", "Assists", "Goals", "Goals"), "team" ="FSU", "prev_action" = "text")

#code not working as expecting
ifelse( x$action == "Goals" & lag(x$action) == "Assists" & lag(x$team) == x$team,
        x$prev_action <- "Assists",x$prev_action <- "IDK")
```

After running the code the console displays:

```
[1] "IDK"     "Assists" "IDK"     "Assists" "IDK"
```

...but if I run this...

```
print(x$prev_action)
[1] "IDK" "IDK" "IDK" "IDK" "IDK"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove the `<-` inside the `ifelse` and place it outside

```
x$prev_action <- ifelse( x$action == "Goals" & 
           lag(x$action) == "Assists" & lag(x$team) == x$team,
                        "Assists","IDK")
x$prev_action
#[1] "IDK"     "Assists" "IDK"     "Assists" "IDK"
```

Comment: That works! But I'm still not sure what is wrong with the original code. Especially if I want to pass a second value if true. Say I also want to grab the previous ID and add: x$prev_ID <- lag(x$ID) to the ifelse statement?

Comment: @seansteele witihiin the `ifelse`, `<-` iis not recommended

Comment: thank you. How would I perform multiple calcs based on one if statement?

Comment: @seansteele it is not clear from the comments.  Can you please post as a new question